# C++ unexpected destructor behavior

Tags: c++, boost, destructor

When I run the following code, I see the sptr pointer is NULL inside the B destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
class B
{
public:
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout<< "B Dtor ";
        // Access sptr
    }

    void RunB()
    {
        sptr.reset(new int(2));
    }

private:
   boost::shared_ptr<int> sptr;
};

class A
{
public:
    void RunA()
    {
        b[1].RunB();
    }
private:
    B b[1];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    A a;
    a.RunA();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I change B b[1] to B b i.e. from an array to a regular object, the sptr point is NOT NULL inside the B desctructor. Why? Can someone please help? I'm completely clueless here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout<< "B Dtor ";
        // Access sptr
    }

    void RunB()
    {
        sptr.reset(new int(2));
    }

private:
   boost::shared_ptr<int> sptr;
};

class A
{
public:
    void RunA()
    {
        b.RunB();
    }
private:
    B b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    A a;
    a.RunA();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++ indexing of arrays starts from 0. So if you have an array of size 1, then to access the first element you need to do `b[0]` not `b[1]`.